# Get view position in window

Tags: mobile, view, titanium

Is it possible to get the absolute position of a View in a Titanium Window? I'm trying to overlay a rectangle on an ImageView, and I need to do a bounds check to see if the rectangle is exiting the bounds of the view.(I've registered a touchmove event handler to the window, as it doesn't seem to fire the event on the ImageView itself).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I solved my own problem by overlaying a normal view and checking the touchmove event on that instead. That gave me coordinates relative to the overlayed view(and the ImageView) which was what I needed.